# Node.JS cannot find json file, everything is right

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-modules

When I'm using my test application, I get this error:

```js
C:\Users\****\Downloads\noded.js website tetstst>node app.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'd.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\*****\Downloads\noded.js website tetstst\app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\****\Downloads\noded.js website tetstst\app.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\*****\\Downloads\\noded.js website tetstst\\app.js' ]
}
```

My code is:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs')
const details = require('d.json')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index')
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
    const email = req.body.email
    const username = req.body.username
    if(!details[username]) {
        details[username] = {
            "email": email,
            "password": "plain"
        }
        const password = bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                details[username].password = hash
            });
        });
    }else{
        if(details[username]){
            return res.render('index', {weather: 'Pass!' + username, error: null});
        }else{
            return res.render('index', {weather: 'No User Found For:' + username, error: null});
        }
    }
    
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

This is my directory image:

[image: Directory]

Hopefully someone could answer and save me and other people's time.

My OS:

Windows 64 Bit Windows Home 10
Node.JS Version 12.8.1 LTS
Visual Studio Code (not sure if that matters)

Comment: If the json is same directory with your nodejs file you need to require it with `const details = require('./d.json')` so it can look current directory. If you won't give any path it will look into `node_modules`

Comment: . /d.json would be required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const details = require('d.json')
```

> everything is right

No, it isn't.  Try using an explicit path relative to the working directory, like this:

```
const details = require('./d.json')
```

From [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/):

> The rules of where require finds the files can be a little complex, but a simple rule of thumb is that if the file doesn't start with "./" or "/", then it is either considered a core module (and the local Node.js path is checked), or a dependency in the local node_modules folder. If the file starts with "./" it is considered a relative file to the file that called require.

Comment: tysm! this helped so much, i can't even put it into words.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following [link](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-and-write-json-file-using-node-js/amp/)

```
const details = require('./d')
const data = require('path/to/file/filename');
```